# DRY on a conditional to calculate prices

Tags: javascript

I have this snippet of code where I add multiple fallbacks if the `price` value equals a 0 (meaning that it couldn't retrieve a price from a URL)

```
url = StarCityController.getSearchURLForCard(cardName, cardNumber, set, foil, variantNumber, true, false);
url = url.replaceAll('★', '').replaceAll('†', '');
soup = await StarCityController.createSoupForCard(url);
price = await StarCityController.getPriceForCard(soup);

if (price === 0) {
    if (!cardNumber.includes('★')) {
        url = StarCityController.getSearchURLForCard(cardName, cardNumber, set, foil, variantNumber, false, false);
    } else {
        url = StarCityController.getSearchURLForCard(cardName, cardNumber, set, true, variantNumber, false, false);
    }
    url = url.replaceAll('★', '').replaceAll('†', '');
    soup = await StarCityController.createSoupForCard(url);
    price = await StarCityController.getPriceForCard(soup);

    if (price === 0) {
        if (!cardNumber.includes('★')) {
            url = StarCityController.getSearchURLForCard(cardName, cardNumber, set, foil, variantNumber, false, true);
        } else {
            url = StarCityController.getSearchURLForCard(cardName, cardNumber, set, true, variantNumber, false, true);
        }
        url = url.replaceAll('★', '').replaceAll('†', '');
        soup = await StarCityController.createSoupForCard(url);
        price = await StarCityController.getPriceForCard(soup);

        if (price === 0) {
            url = StarCityController.getImageSearchURLForCard(cardName, cardNumber, set);
            soup = await StarCityController.createSoupForCard(url);
            price = await StarCityController.getPriceForCardInScryfall(soup, foil);
        }
    }
}
```

The last if is usually my last resort if everything else fails. As you can see, there's a lot of variables in the `getSearchURLForCard` call, since the URL can have multiple values for a number (for example, it can have a `003` instead of a `3` or vice-versa).

How can I rewrite this in order to enforce DRY? Maybe I could put all of this in another method, but that won't solve the main problem at hand. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that I can flip the `cardNumber.includes('★')` conditional in order to save myself from the `!` operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In situations where you have one or more "fallback" algorithms, consider refactoring each calculation into its own function. Then you can use the `||` operator between function calls, since you check for a zero price, which is falsey:

```
let price = calculatePriceA(...)
         || calculatePriceB(...)
         || calculatePriceC(...)
         || calculatePriceD(...);
```

This works well in cases where the arguments to each function are known ahead of time, and do not rely on values that change after attempting to calculate a price. Alternately, you can store functions in an array and loop over them until you get a price:

```
let calculators = [
    calculatePriceA,
    calculatePriceB,
    calculatePriceC,
    calculatePriceD
];

let price = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < calculators.length; i++) {
    if (price = calculators[i](x, y, z)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This can accommodate a dynamic list of price calculators.

If the arguments for these functions become inconsistent, consider refactoring the calculators into an array of objects, and passing most arguments to the constructor:

```
let calculators = [
    new CalculatorA(a, b, c),
    new CalculatorB(c, b, d),
    new CalculatorC(d, e, f, a, g),
    new CalculatorD(c, b, a)
];

for (let i = 0; i < calculators.length; i++) {
    if (price = calculators[i].calculatePrice(x, y, z)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

These techniques can help you reduce nested `if` statements, and reduce the number of times you need to check `if (price == 0)`, but since each calculation is a little different, there is little common code between them.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down and encapsulating the code base in an object makes it cleaner and avoids mutation. You can cut out unnecessary code and redundancy with ternaries, recursion and gate clauses.

Here's what I did. Not tested, so not sure if it will work out of the box but hopefully it gives you some ideas.

```js
// Methods
const priceCalc = {

    async getPrice(url, foil) {
        const searchUrl = foil
            ? StarCityController.getImageSearchURLForCard(cardName, cardNumber, set)
            : url.replaceAll('★', '').replaceAll('†', '');

        const soup = await StarCityController.createSoupForCard(searchUrl);

        const price = foil
            ? await StarCityController.getPriceForCardInScryfall(soup, foil)
            : await StarCityController.getPriceForCard(soup);

        return price
    },

    finalPath(name, number, set) {
        return StarCityController.getImageSearchURLForCard(name, number, set)
    },

    async initialResults(card) {

        const url = StarCityController.getSearchURLForCard(...card, true, false);
        const price = await priceCalc.getPrice(url);
    
        return { price, card }
    },

    async nestedResultsPrice(card, boolX = false) {

        const { name, number, set, foil, variant } = card;

        const fVal = number.includes('★') ? true : foil;
        const url = StarCityController.getSearchURLForCard(name, number, set, fVal, variant, false, boolX);

        const price = await priceCalc.getPrice(url);
    
        if (price > 0) {
            return price
        }
    
        const priceResult = boolX
            ? await priceCalc.getPrice(
                StarCityController.getImageSearchURLForCard(name, number, set), 
                foil
            )
            : await priceCalc.nestedResultsPrice(card, true);
    
        return priceResult;
    }
}

// Call function
const getSearchPrice = async (cardResults) => {

    const { price, card } = await priceCalc.initialResults(cardResults)

    const priceResult = price === 0
        ? await priceCalc.nestedResultsPrice(card)
        : price;

    return priceResult;
}

const price = await getSearchPrice({
    name: cardName,
    number: cardNumber,
    set,
    foil,
    variant: variantNumber
})
```